# Multi navigation failed in layout

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-view, zend-navigation

why second var_dump() display null in this code in my layout.phtml :

```
var_dump(($this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->render()));

var_dump(($this->navigation('navigation')->breadcrumbs()->render()));
```

output :

```
    string '<ul class="navigation">
    <li>
        <a href="/en/admin">DashBoard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/en/admin/members">Members Management</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="/en/admin/events">Events</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/en/admin/events/categories">Categories</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/en/admin/events">Show All</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href='... (length=802)

string '' (length=0)
```

**EDIT :**

actually changing var_dump order ... OMG ... again the second one is NULL !! :-O
Output :

```
string '<a href="/en/admin/events">Events</a> &gt; Show All' (length=51)

string '' (length=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in zf2 ver <= 2.1.3 about this and its closed but not yet merged into production package and will be fixed in next minor release
https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/3976
Simple solution :
https://github.com/froschdesign/zf2/commit/454439d35716ed2125a6ac90c826836f57391eb0

Answer (score -1):

the contents on breadcrumbs will depends where the output is executed.

for example, if you are inside a controller and action which has been assigned to one of your navigation items, then it should be picked up.

I suspect you haven't setup navigation pages for the controller/action pairing where you are performing the var_dump.

Example nav config:

```
array(
'navigation' => array(
     'default' => array(
         array(
             'label' => 'Page One',
             'route' => 'myroute',
             'controller' => 'categories',
             'action' => 'list',
         ),
```

If you perform your output in the listAction method of your Categories controller then the breadcrumb helper should return something for you

Comment: that's very strange, you can definitely use both together without issue i've done it. very strange

Comment: how have you setup your nav? what service manager config have you got etc, you haven't got it set to "not shared" have you?

Comment: nice, i've used them both together with no issue and not seen this :)